# HipHop (PHP) acceleration for SquirrelMail?

Tags: webmail, squirrelmail, php

Has anybody ever tried [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php) or any other PHP acceleration method for SquirrelMail? Was it a plug-and-play thing, or did it require significant modification of the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SquirrelMail would require a large amount of rewrites to work with HipHop, because of the magic calls it relies on such as eval() in the gettext class.

APC's optimization for SquirrelMail should suit most needs, and Rasmus' talk at Digg about PHP optimization really articulates why that is: http://about.digg.com/blog/rasmus-lerdorf-php-performance